# why are my php object member variables null after instantiating them?

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I'm trying to make an api in php. In this part I query my database and load the data into chuckquote objects then add those objects to an array to be encoded in json and received whenever the app sends a get request.
When I echo the query results every thing comes out fine but if i echo the id right after it gets instantiated its something completely different and when I encode the array everything is NULL and there is a 5th blank row that now contains the dates. How do I fix this or at least what am i doing wrong here ?

```
    if($method == "GET")
    {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM chuckquotes";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {

      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
      {
        //echo " " . $row["ID"] . " " . $row["quote"] . " " . $row["author"] . " " . $row["datentime"] . " " ;
        $crow = new chuckquote;

        echo $crow->$id = $row["ID"];
        $crow->$quote = $row["quote"];
        $crow->$author = $row["author"];
        $crow->$date = $row["datentime"];


        $Jsonarray[] = $crow;


      }

      echo json_encode($Jsonarray);

    }
    else
    {
      echo "0 results";
    }

    $conn->close();

    }
```

Class

```
  class chuckquote
    {
      public $id;
      public $quote;
      public $author;
      public $date;
    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{"id":null,"quote":null,"author":null,"date":null,"":"2019-02-17 06:47:13"},{"id":null,"quote":null,"author":null,"date":null,"":"2019-02-17 06:47:13"},{"id":null,"quote":null,"author":null,"date":null,"":"2019-02-17 06:47:13"},{"id":null,"quote":null,"author":null,"date":null,"":"2019-02-17 06:47:13"}]
```

Comment: turn on display warnings/errors, remove the echo `echo $crow->$id = $row["ID"];` , change `$crow->$quote = $row["quote"];` to `$crow->quote = $row["quote"];`

Comment: Yeah I accidently left that first part in there from testing .. but that was the problem removing the $ worked. Thanks!

Comment: `echo "0 results";` ...if you're going to output JSON when there _are_ results, it would make sense to also echo JSON when there aren't. That way the client gets a consistent response in a consistent format. In fact the best way to indicate 0 results in cases where you return a list would be simply to return an empty array. You are then conveying the pure data, as-is. It's then up to the client how it decides to deal with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `$` sign from the property name. From

```
echo $crow->$id = $row["ID"];
$crow->$quote = $row["quote"];
$crow->$author = $row["author"];
$crow->$date = $row["datentime"];
```

to

```
$crow->id = $row["ID"];
$crow->quote = $row["quote"];
$crow->author = $row["author"];
$crow->date = $row["datentime"];
```

In php, you don't need to use `$` sign while accessing a class property.

Although it's best practice to create a constructor for this assignment. Example class with constructor.

```
class chuckquote
{
    public $id;
    public $quote;
    public $author;
    public $date;

    /**
     * chuckquote constructor.
     * @param $id
     * @param $quote
     * @param $author
     * @param $date
     */
    public function __construct($id, $quote, $author, $date)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->quote = $quote;
        $this->author = $author;
        $this->date = $date;
    }
}
```

And then you can assign the values when instantiate the class.

```
$crow = new chuckquote($row["ID"], $row["quote"], $row["author"], $row["datentime"]);
```

Comment: removing the echo would also make sense. Seems to be unnecessary, and would cause anything trying to parse the whole response as JSON to fail

Comment: I guess he used it for debugging purpose. Although it's a bad practice.

Comment: Exactly, so it needs removing

Comment: I removed the echo. Also added an example of assigning values using constructor.